# how to getSystemService within a ContentProvider in android?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have class structure like this:

```
public class DHTContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
    private Networking networking = new Networking();
    public boolean onCreate() {
         networking.init();
    }
    public class Networking extends Service {
         public void init() {
              TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
         }
    }
}
```

Networking is a subclass of DHTContentProvider.
When I run it always NullPointerException. Anyone has idea?

Answer (score 0):

Call `getContext()` to retrieve a `Context`, then call `getSystemService()` on that Context.

Comment: I also tried this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(). It also doesn't work.

Comment: @zwx: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#getContext()

Comment: I have the same problem @CommonsWare and this actually worked for me. So thank you very much. But I am not sure how it works. WHen I called the `ContentProvider` from my `MainActivity`, does `getContext()` get that? I just want to make sure I understand how it works.

Comment: @Andy: `getContext()` returns a generic `Context` made available to a `ContentProvider`. You should not assume what sort of `Context` it is, just that it honors the `Context` API.

Comment: Does it matter when using it to call things you need from `Context`? Say like calling a `getSystemService()`.

Comment: @Andy: No, `getSystemService()` should work with any `Context`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should delete them "Context.".